# How this line execute and stop synchronisation of cin?

Tags: c++, runtime

```
// Filename : cin_test_2.cc to see
// performance of cin() with stdio syc
// disabled using sync_with_stdio(false).
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char buffer[256];
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    while (cin >> buffer)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is written to compare the speed of cin and scanf(). It is found that adding( ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)) this makes cin fast as it stops the synchronisation.
So please explain how this line executes and how it stop synchronisation of cin.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you read [std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)? If so, what was unclear?

Comment: I read that but i just want to know the flow of this statement . how this statement is going to execute?